# Hide wp-content in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a local Wordpress server where the index.php is called when i navigate to the folder containing wp-content. So the URL now shows no kind of Wordpress stuff. But if I navigate to another Page within the same template, the URL looks like this: 'sameasbefore/wp-content/themes/themename/target'.
Can anyone tell me how to make the URL look like this: 'sameasbefore/target'?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, Add this to your wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'YOUR_LOCAL_PATH' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'YOUR_PUBLIC_PATH' );
```

Hope this will work for you.

For more information,

- [Hide wp-content from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325481/hide-wp-content-from-url)
- [hide wp-content from urls](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37334/hide-wp-content-from-urls)
- [MASKING WP-CONTENT/INCLUDES USING .HTACCESS](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/masking-wp-contentincludes-using-htaccess)

Comment: so my local path would be localhost/foo/wp-content/themes/bar/

Comment: YOUR_LOCAL_PATH is the original path while YOUR_PUBLIC_PATH is what I wanted to be seen.